# Round function doesn't keep the decimals

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I want to round all the values in a column to 2 decimal points. In the following example, I am expecting to update all the values to `111.27`:

First I update all the rows with a `varchar` type

```
update someTable
    set cash = '111.2659516';
```

Now I want to round all these values. If I cast the `varchar`

```
update someTable
    set cash = round(cast(cash as double precision), 2);
```

I will get this as the result

```
111.27000000000001
111.27000000000001
111.27000000000001
111.27000000000001
```

If I don't cast the values, I will get this as the result

```
111
111
111
111
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Store your value as a `decimal`/`numeric`, not with floating point values.

Comment: https://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: @GordonLinoff I don't have any control on the value insertion. I just added that part to the question as an example.

Comment: cast as numeric? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2f787d5e0afd5b06aab74e75b9499a2f

Comment: @Nick for some weird reason numeric gives me 111 too

Comment: @Yar seems to work fine in the demo... are you using a different version than I did? or perhaps a different data type for `cash`?

Comment: The Data Type is the same but I am using PostgreSQL 8.0.2

Comment: I added `precision` and `scale` to the numeric casting and finally it's working! Thank you @Nick. If you can add the answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Yar that's interesting, even in 8.4 it works without precision and scale. Also it would appear that if you cast with a scale of 2 you don't need to round. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=37226b37a25f11d4815aff2ddefaa14a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
update someTable
    set cash = cast(cash as decimal(18,2))
```